# How to customize Flask Admin templates?

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I'm trying to RTL the flask admin template, I know I can override the existing templates, but how do I change only the CSS? Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Put your CSS changes in a new CSS file in `/static/css/my_flask_admin.css`.

Then [override](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#overriding-the-built-in-templates) the HTML template. This can be done by creating a file called `/templates/admin/master.html` with the following contents:

```
{% extends admin_base_template %}

{% block head_css %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/my_flask_admin.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

The `extends` and `block` calls inherit the original template and hook into the CSS definitions. The `super()` call loads the original CSS files. The `url_for(...)` call appends your CSS file after those, effectively prioritizing your file over the originals.

Comment: Saved me some time.

Comment: Partial answer. Where is the HTML template, where does it go?

Comment: @cal97g Have a look at https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin . For example you can use the simple example in the examples subdirectory: Put your css file in the newly created static/css subdirectory. Then you can past the above snippet in its template/admin/index.html file directly after the first and befor the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the environment variable `FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH` on your flask app was a life-saver for me not having to mess with overriding any HTML.

eg. `FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH = 'litera'`